# How do I match a word in a text file using python?

Tags: python, string, match, text-files

I want to search and match a particular word in a text file.

```
with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if word in line:
                    print line
```

This code returns even the words that contain substrings of the target word. For example if the word is "there" then the search returns "there", "therefore", "thereby", etc.

I want the code to return only the lines which contain "there". Period.

Answer (score 7):

```
import re

file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    if re.search('^there$', line, re.I):
        print line
```

The `re.search` function scans the string `line` and returns true if it finds the regular expression defined in the first parameter, ignoring case with `re.I`. The `^` character means 'beginning of the line' while the `$` character means 'end of the line'. Therefore, the search function will only return true if it matches *there* preceded by the beginning of the line, and followed by the end of the line, aka isolated on its own.

Comment: Some explanation of the code would be nice, since it's clear the OP isn't familiar with the regex concept.

Comment: wouldn't this have the same problem? maybe '^* there *$' would be better?

Comment: It's hard to match all the corner cases without any indication of what the input looks like. `\bthere\b` might be better than `^there$`.

Comment: The input file contains two columns: for example-   
50677                    undermined

Answer (score 5):

split the line into tokens: `if word in line.split():`

Comment: Probably the more performant solution compared to regex, but it might break in corner cases (I can't say for sure because I don't know what the input looks like). +1 for simplicity.

Comment: you're welcome. but as the other guys said, learn regexes. it takes a while, but it's worth it. *pydoc re*

Answer (score 2):

You can always use regex, something along the lines of:

```
import re

with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if re.search( r'\sthere\s', line, re.M|re.I):
                    print line
```

- `\sthere\s` - any space followed by 'there' followed by any space
- `re.I` - means case insensitive
- `re.M` - doesn't really matter in this case (since lines only have 1 \n)

Comment: Something like r'\bthere\b' would be better. `\b` matches a word boundary without consuming characters like `\s` does.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to use a regular expression. The [regular expression howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) from the Python docs might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the re module (regular expressions).  re.search with the regex ' there ' is what you want.