# Python: match a single word (with spaces)

Tags: python, regex, wildcard

The problem is that I am trying to match a word (spaces on either side) if it exists.

The code I have working (at least mostly) is:

```
import re, os

str1 = "the host offered $ rec*ting advice"
str1 = re.sub('[*]', '(.*?)', str1)
str1 = re.sub('[$]', '(.*?)', str1)
str1 = str1.lower()
print str1
previous_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('testfilefolder')
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_contents = f.read().lower()
    output = re.search("%s" % str1, file_contents)
    if output:
        print (" Match found in " + filename))
```

So for example if I have the string `"the host has offered some recruiting advice"` and do a search on the string `"the host offered some $ rec*ting advice"`  it will not work - due to the dollar sign (which is replaced by the `(.*?)`.  The interesting thing is, if I have `"the host offered $ rec*ting advice"` - note "some" is gone and hence this works - so I can match 1 word if it exists -looks like `(.*?)` is supposed to match one character which each word has at least one character in it so I suppose that is why it works.  I am not sure if the `(.*?)` is even right to use but it is the best that I have gotten working so far after my research. Any advice on that would be very appreciated.  Note above I have `(.*?)` in the text it seems to show up that somehow the `(.*?)` is some sort of tag and just formats the string between the `(.*?)`'s.

I however want to match 0 or 1 word.  I had found something before similar to \bs+\b (I can't quite remember and I can't find it again), but couldn't get it to work anyways.  I know that \b is supposed to match an empty string on either side of the possible existence of a word.

I appologize if this question is asked elsewhere but it seems that everything I have found (that I can still find and was able to get working) is looking for a particular word - I however am looking to see if only 0 or 1 exists:

[How do I match a word in a text file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228448/how-do-i-match-a-word-in-a-text-file-using-python)

Comment: The webpage example that I was referring to is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228448/how-do-i-match-a-word-in-a-text-file-using-python

Comment: The second argument to `sub` is the *replacement* pattern. Anything matched by `[*]` (one asterisk) is replaced by the second string `(.*?)`, which only supports replacement placeholders referring to captured groups.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. To match a word with spaces either side: `re.search(' yourword ', str1)`. How does that not meet your requirements?

Comment: Martijn, I am a little confused on the "replacement placeholders" are you saying that the (.*?) only holds a place if something is captured?  Thus since there is nothing there it is not capturing anything and hence doesn't match anything?

Comment: Sorry about that MikeM, I added the rest of the code for clarification as I forgot to include a piece.  I however am not trying to match any particular word - actually there might not be a word, this is where I am having trouble as the (.*?) matches any single word that exists but if a word doesn't exist I would still like it to return true that the original searched for string ""the host offered $ rec*ting advice" is found.

Comment: The regex `"the host offered (\S+ )?rec\S+ting advice"` would allow an optional word before "recruiting", and would also allow "recruiting" to match if it is in some ways mispelt. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MikeM.  I can not seem to get that to work in the form:

str1 = "the host offered $ $ rec*ting advice"
#the host offered (\S+ )?rec\S+ting advice
str1 = re.sub('[*]', '\S+', str1)
str1 = re.sub('[$]', '(\S+)?', str1)

I can get it to work with one $, but not $ $.  In the file there is "the host has offered some recruiting advice", so the one $ matches the word "some", but with 2 $ $ in a row I am trying to get the regex to match 0, 1, or 2 words.  If there were say $ $ $ $ $ I would want it to match 0 to 5 words that could exist - but don't have to.  \

Comment: Don't leave a space between the `$`. The `(\S+ )?` already has the space in it. Or better, change `(\S+ )?` to `(\S+ ){1,5}`, to allow one to five words for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your question is very hard to understand so this is probably not exactly what you are looking for but it may help you in the right direction.*

If you want to find all words in the text this is how it could be done:

```
import re
str1 = "the host offered $ rec*ting advice"
re.findall(r'\b\S+\b',str1)
```

This will produce:

```
['the', 'host', 'offered', 'rec*ting', 'advice']
```

The `\b`-thing in the pattern is not actually matching a character, but a place in the string where a word starts or ends (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re for more info on this).

The dollar sign is not considered a word since its not a *word* character according to the `\b`-definition used.

If you want to get the first word in a string if there is a word there to get you could use:

```
re.findall(r'\b\S+\b',str1)[:1]
```

You will then get a list of zero or one element!